# SEO for websites with very less content and a lot of images

Tags: seo, content, photo-gallery, image-search

Let's say we have an image exhibition website that has got a lot of images but next to nothing content. The focus keyword for this website is "Artistic wallpapers".
What would be the best approach w.r.t SEO for such a website.

Here are a few things I can imagine:

- Submitting sitemaps ( image and web )
- Having a good pagespeed score.
- Nice navigation
- Breadcrumbs
- sharing the website content on Social media.
- Having appropriate titles.

Having worked on all these things, what can be done if Search engines are picking wrong keywords ( For example views, votes, ratings) Can anything be done so that Search engines don't track these specific items?
Also, is it a good practice to have all the pages submitted to Search engines at once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd also consider the use of captions and meaningful image filenames. Another common approach is to implement a tagging system - SE's will be somewhat wary because this could be abused, but it's certainly a way of telling search engines what the content of the image is.

Also consider comment/discussion facilities - let visitors provide you with content and keywords. Might be more hassle than you want, and might not be appropriate  for the tone of your site.

Use sensible and explicit categorization - organise the images into sensible groups and the navigation and page headers/titles will do a lot for you.

Consider also some wordy pages that outline your site, the organisation, the type of content you hold, the way it is organised. Done right, it might be of interest to human visitors and bots alike.

Create articles possibly about your site, but more likely about the subject matter of your site. Host it locally, but offer them up to other sites that are interested in this subject area. As a minimum you'll get a link back in return, but hopefully some interest and goodwill from the visitors to those sites.

In short, search engines love text content, so you need to provide some that is contextually appropriate and fits in with the style and purpose of your site - give search engines something to digest, something that they can latch onto.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put unique page titles at the top of that list.  Duplicate titles will kill you.  You also need to use the meta description field and populate that if possible the photo description text.